# Get list of memberships for a user from the users model using generic listview

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I want to create a view that shows a list of memberships fot a specific CustomUser. The view i have only shows a list of memberships for the logged in user. How can i achive this with generic.listview?

i want the list to show all the memberships for a specific user by passing the PK from CusomUser can anybody help me with this?

****URL****

```
path('<int:pk>/membership/', views.MemberShipIndex.as_view(), name='MemberShipIndex'),
```

**View**

```
class MemberShipIndex(generic.ListView):
    model = Membership
    template_name = 'members/membership_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'membership_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.filter(CustomUser=self.request.user)
```

Comment: Please share your model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter on the `pk` parameter:

```
class MemberShipIndex(generic.ListView):
    model = Membership
    template_name = 'members/membership_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'membership_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.filter(CustomUser_id=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

---

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PerlCase*, so it should be: `custom_user` instead of <s>`CustomUser`</s>.

Comment: Willem you are a genius, thank you im new to Django. I will try to use snake case in the future.